# 'Discerning the Transmundane' quest not working

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did everything for the quest up until harvesting the blood: after I went and harvested the blood I went back to Septimus and now he won't give me any options about giving him the Essence Extractor back.
Any clues as to why this might have happened and how to fix it?

Comment: what does your quest say to do next?

Comment: i couldn't find anything that worked so i just didn't do the quest, when i finished the dragon born dlc  hermaeus mora told me about  how i already finished the quest, i just gave myself the book and moved on i think what happened was the game already thought the mission concluded so i couldn't do anything with it

Answer (score 1):

This is a very buggy quest. The bugs are listed in detail here:

https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane#Bugs

The Unofficial Patch will fix most of the bugs, including yours.

> You may not have the "Harvest blood" option despite having the Essence
> Extractor in your inventory.
>
> PC Only: This bug is fixed by version 2.0.1 of the Unofficial Skyrim
> Patch.

> PC: Use the console command `player.addperk 79af5`.

However, this option is only available if you have the PC version.